# IntelliJ getter/setter format (single-line versus multi-line)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, getter-setter

How can you get [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) to generate getter/setters accessor methods on one line like this:

```
public String getAbc() { return abc; }
```

… instead of multiple lines like this:

```
public String getAbc() {
   return abc;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are no templates neither for getters nor for equals/hashcode. These are hardcoded in IDEA.

[Source](http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/thread/182697;jsessionid=1FC4A4DFB95610F09D114E0A6F2C5CE5)

You can see that in this [IntelliJ Wishlist](http://plugins.intellij.net/wishlist/show?pr=&wid=99)

Comment: There are now (I use Ultimate 2016) - see answers below

Answer (score 38):

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.0 and you can customise this behaviour.

Just use the "Generate..." option, or use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> shortcut, and select "Getter and Setter".

In the "Select Fields" window that gets opened, you have the "Getter Template" option at the top. Use the "..." button next to the dropdown, to edit the template.

Select "IntelliJ Default" and click the "Copy" button to create a new one named "AlwayStartWithGet", which you can edit.

Just remove the following section:

```
#if ($field.boolean)
  #if ($StringUtil.startsWithIgnoreCase($name, 'is'))
    #set($name = $StringUtil.decapitalize($name))
  #else
    is##
#end
#else
  get##
#end
```

And replace it with a simple

```
get##
```

You should be left with:

```
public ##
#if($field.modifierStatic)
  static ##
#end
$field.type ##
#set($name = $StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($helper.getPropertyName($field, $project))))
get##
${name}() {
  return $field.name;
}
```

Now you can use the custom template when generating code, by selecting it in the getter template dropdown.

Comment: This looks promising but I am not seeing a Getter template button  to the top of this dialog. Using 14.0.2.

Comment: Worked for me, but to be precise last part of the template should look like:

    `${name}() {  return $field.name; }`

in one line

Comment: Make sure to check also Settings/code Style/Java/Simple blocks in one line and Simple Methods in one line. Otherwise, the auto-formatting will put the lines right back in and you don't see any effect after modifying the template...

Comment: This applies to Android Studio as well.

Answer (score 13):

For Idea 2016.

**Getter template**

Merge the last 3 lines into a single line:

```
${name}() { return $field.name; }
```

**Setter template**

Add double hash (without a space) at the end of the longest line:

```
[...] ($field.type, $paramName) {##
```

Merge the last 2 lines into a single line:

```
$field.name = $paramName; }
```

*Note: as commented by @mindas, you will probably want instead the visual auto folding that doesn't get versioned.*

Comment: Ah, so `##` here is like ``\`` in C++, I guess?

Answer (score 11):

You didn't mention what version of IDEA you are using, so I assume the recent 8 or 9.

Check your Code Style settings, under "Alignment and Braces". You should find a "Simple methods in one line" option there.

Comment: Did you try unchecking the related "Line breaks" box in the "Keep When Reformatting" group?

Comment: The one-line setting tells IntelliJ to leave it that way on a reformat, but not to create it that way.

Comment: is this a programing language? or could you give us some links or references?

Answer (score 10):

I don't know why you want to do this, presumably for saving visual space. If so, just use IntelliJ's feature to fold trivial getters/setters and forget about how lines does it take.
Folding feature can be found in

Settings -> IDE Settings -> Editor -> Code Folding -> Show code folding outline -> Simple property accessors

Comment: As of 2019.1, this feature can be found in Settings -> Editor -> General -> Code Folding.  Simple property accessors is in the third checkbox cluster.

Answer (score 5):

Alex G and laffuste provided answers that helped me, but even after you follow these instructions, IntelliJ may still automatically format your code.  To stop this from happening, go to Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java (or other language).  Click on the tab titled "Wrapping and Braces".  Under the title "Keep when reformatting" click the checkbox next to "Simple methods in one line".

For further brevity, you can eliminate the blank lines between the getter and setter methods.  To do this, click on the tab titled "Blank Lines".  In the section titled "Minimum Blank Lines", find the text box next to "Around method".  Enter 0 in the text box.

#### Get

```
public ##
#if($field.modifierStatic)
static ##
#end
$field.type ##
#set($name = $StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($helper.getPropertyName($field, $project))))
get##
${name}(){ return $field.name; }
```

#### Set

```
#set($paramName = $helper.getParamName($field, $project))
#if($field.modifierStatic)
static ##
#end
void set$StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($helper.getPropertyName($field, $project)))($field.type $paramName) { ##
#if ($field.name == $paramName)
    #if (!$field.modifierStatic)
    this.##
    #else
        $classname.##
    #end
#end
$field.name = $paramName; }
```

Comment: It appears this is necessary for IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.

Comment: When trying to do this again, I had to go over answers provided by Alex G and laffuste.  The two of them combined have a nearly complete answer, but not something I could just copy-paste.  I provided code here hoping it can be pasted in the correct location without tinkering.

Answer (score 0):

Update for at least versions as new as 2023.1.2:

You'll need to also make sure that the following setting is also turned on:

- Preferences > Editor > Code Style > Java > Spaces > Within

  - Code Braces

Otherwise the spaces between your curly braces will be formatted away.