# Android Studio (IntelliJ IDEA) How do you setup getters without get prefix?

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

If I have a member variable `private int mScore` how do I setup Android Studio so it generates the following getters and setters?

```
public int score() {
  return mScore;
}

public void setScore(int score) {
  mScore = score;
}
```

So instead of getScore() I'd have only score().

Comment: Actually this is possible : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26622885/how-set-prefix-e-g-m-to-remove-in-android-studios-alt-insert-getter-setter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't like this answer, but [you can't do that in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785244/intellij-getter-setter-format).

That said, I'm curious what your reason is for wanting to do it that way. It's strongly against the Java convention, as well as conventions used in the Android SDK, so you'll inevitably be introducing a conflicting pattern into your code base. You may be interested in [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/) for reducing boilerplate though, specifically the `@Setter` and `@Getter` annotations.

Comment: I'm porting a project from Objective C and I wanted to keep things consistent. Probably not a good idea.

Comment: You don't want to prefix your object's private attributes with `m` either.

Comment: As a fellow Objective-C and Java developer, I would suggest the "when in Rome" rule. Stick with getThing() in Java. (I'm also not a fan of prefixing variable names, since IDEs are very good at pointing scope out, but that's another topic and less polarized by language.)