# How set prefix (e.g. "m") to remove in Android Studio's Alt-Insert getter/setter?

Tags: android, android-studio

I make most of my member variables start with the letter "m", for example `mId` or `mIsSomething`. When I use the keyboard shortcut to add getters/setters, I end up with:

```
public void setmId() {}
```

but I want:

```
public void getId() {}
```

How do I set a prefix for it to remove when creating the getter/setter?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I found the solution:

Go to `File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings`

In the search box, type "prefix".

On the right, select the tab "Code Generation".

In the "prefix" box, type `m` (or whatever your prefix is)

Comment: What is the difference between `Other Settings` and `Settings`? The same options are available in `Settings>Code Style>Java>Code Generation`

Comment: @donniezazen it would appear that Other Settings is for a quick selection more than anything. Settings opens up the full menu.

Comment: In the latest version of Android Studio I was not able to use 'prefix' in the search box to find the required setting. I had to manually go to `preferences -> code style -> java` to see the required options page.

Comment: @BrentM did you report it as a bug?

Comment: I haven't reported it as a bug and I haven't checked the AS 1.3 preview version.

Answer (score 46):

1. Open  Default Settings (`File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings`)
2. Go to `Editor -> Java -> Code Generation`
3. Select `Prefer longer names`
4. Enter `m` in Field as prefix

[image]

Comment: The screenshot was useful for me, @DonRhummy. I skimmed through the accepted answer unsuccessfully a few times before I gave up. This answer took me a matter of seconds to correctly interpret and accomplish my goal.